# Json De-Serialization is leading UTC to local Time by default issue

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I am trying to de-serialize using Object mapper for the message which is being received by Listener through IBM MQ.

MY POJO class is :-

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

/**
 * This class is used for JSON placeholder for gate out message from YMS
 *
 */
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OutMessage {

    @JsonProperty("routeNbr")
    private Integer routeNbr;

    @JsonProperty("tNbr")
    private String tNbr;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ")
    @JsonProperty("tDepartedTS")
    private Date tDepartedTS;

    @JsonProperty("dcNbr")
    private String dcNbr;

    @JsonProperty("userID")
    private String userID;
}
```

I have not put getter and setter here.

When JMS message listener received the following JSON message :-

```
{
  "routeNbr": "661",
  "dcNbr": "7390",
  "tNbr": "700159",
  "userID": "CLB003V",
  "tDepartedTS": "2018-07-13 12:01:02.417 UTC"
}
```

And when it tries to do the de-seralization using objectMapper (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper) in Message Listener like this :-

```
OutMessage outMsg = new ObjectMapper().readValue(gateOutMessageString,
                OutMessage.class);
System.out.println(outMsg.gettDepartedTS());
```

It de-serializes successfully. Only problem is that after de-serialization, when application tries to get the **tDepartedTS** , it does not print the UTC given time ("2018-07-13 12:01:02.417 UTC") , but it automatically adds +05:30 to the time and prints **13th July, 2018 17:31:02**

Reason being is that i am running my application from India which is (UTC+05:30). My requirement is that when i do get operation for tDepartedTS after de-serialzation , i should get **13th July, 2018 12:01:02**. It should not convert in any other timezone.

Comment: How do you print the tDepartedTS? Please learn to always provide complete examples.

Comment: you can try adding this annotation on `tDepartedTS` Date field in pojo `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone="UTC")`. This will work WHEN you serialize the Pojo and not when printing the `tDepartedTS` field directly

Comment: I have edit my question for how i am trying to check the value of tDepartedTS.

Comment: @Archit my application is not the source of this message. we get from upstream in this format (pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ" ). i cannot change the format. but i am still not able to figure out why it is converting to IST timezone while de-serailizing the message.

Comment: Saw you edit after posting comment hence delete my comments.

Comment: When you print Date it is always printed in local timezone. Either you can explicitly set JVM's local timezone to UTC (which may not be feasible), or use Java8 new date-time api (which is basically joda-time library). It gives easy control on printing time in specific timezone

Comment: Is there no way we can achieve with java.util.Date ?

Answer (score 0):

Class java.util.Date contains no timezone information.

As far as it is concerned, 13th July, 2018 17:31:02 Indian time is exactly the same time as 2018-07-13 12:01:02.417 UTC. Because when you don't care about time zone, it is as a matter of fact the same time. It does not come with any kind of ability to make a difference between the two.

Therefore, when you parse a date, UTC, to an object of type java.util.Date, you obtain correct information about the time it represents, but you lose all information about the fact that it was read as UTC.

If you then demand System.out.println() to write out this date, it needs to figure out a human-friendly way to write it out, and the typical way to do that is to write out the date according to a chosen time zone. Since java.util.Date doesn't come with time zone information, System.out.println() chooses one itself, and chooses the computer's default time zone, as it is the only logical choice. You could have used a DateFormat instead to specify how you want this date to be written out, including but not limited to with what time zone.

But really, java.util.Date class and related, are obsolete. You need to upgrade to java 8's new java.time package. In your case, since you're interested in keeping information about time zone, you need to store your times in objects of class `java.time.ZonedDateTime`